# Using a function with a for loop in PySpark map

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, for-loop, pyspark

I'm trying to remove special characters from each word in my RDD:

```
special_characters = '~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};:,<.>/?'
    def remove_special_characters(word):
        for character in special_characters[0: len(special_characters)]:
            word = word.replace(character, '')
            return word
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
words_lower = words.map(lambda word: word.lower())

clean_words_1 = words_lower.map(lambda word: remove_special_characters(word))
clean_words_2 = words_lower.map(remove_special_characters)
```

Only the first special character gets replaced from each word.

Answer (score 0):

return needs to be placed outside of the for loop.